# Decimal separator in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, localization

What do I need to change in Sql Server to be able to store values like "***2,1***" in a decimal field?  Right now I have to have dots like "***2.1***".

I have Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS collation on the database but that doesn't seem to be it ... I also fiddled around with the regions settings on the server but with no success. I know I've managed to change this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In security, your login properties, set default language to Finnish or Swedish.
Although I'd prefer to format values into english standard and have default language set to english - this way storing data is independent of client regional settings.

Comment: Ok. Found it on the server instance under the advanced tab. Thanks.

Comment: There you can set default language for new logins - of course needed too; sorry I forgot that in my response.

Answer (score 5):

Store the data as a regular number - change it only when you display it.

Comment: I need to set up a test database with existing data so this will not work for me

Comment: You can try using @kevchadders idea  to convert the data to the regular representation. on the new database.
if your app reads a regular number - will it fail ?